# Does the product of elements being in a group imply the individual elements are in that group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N$ and $K$ be groups and let $x\in N \cap K$ and $k\in K$. If $kx=x'k$, for some $x'\in N$, does $kx \in N \cap K$ imply that $x' \in K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general question in your title, certainly not.

For the specific question in your question, yes, because
$$x'=(kx)k^{-1}\ ,$$
and by assumption both $kx$ and $k$ (therefore also $k^{-1}$) are in $K$.